# Formatando data para salvar

Tags: java, mysql, sql, data

Olá, preciso converter uma data que está em String para salvar em uma variável `data_inicio` do tipo `Date` no Mysql e fiz da seguinte forma:

```
String data = "14/11/2017";
        SimpleDateFormat formataData = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date dataEntrada = null;
        try {
           // dataEntrada = formataData.parse("21/09/2010");
            dataEntrada = formataData.parse(data);
            System.out.println("data entrada -> "+dataEntrada);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Resuldado gerado por dataEntrada = Tue Nov 14 00:00:00 BRST 2017 mas preciso que essa dataEntrada fique no formato 2017/11/14 para salvar no banco Mysql

Comment: Oi Fabrício. Talvez eu não tenha entendido sua questão, mas depois que você converteu a String para uma `Date` não seria possível fazer o `insert` no banco usando a data convertida? Não sei o que você está usando (`PreparedStatement` `JdbcTemplate`, etc) mas em geral é bem fácil usar o tipo `Date`. Me parece bem estranho fazer `parse` para em seguida fazer um `format`.

Comment: Cara tem umas 3 ou 4 perguntas suas só sobre como mudar formato de data para formado de banco ou formato brasileiro. Sugiro que pare e leia um pouco melhor as respostas que recebeu, pois em todas elas a duvida foi solucionada.

Comment: Cara valeu agora deu certo, eu esta um pouco confuso porque o código retornava uma String e eu achei que devia enviar um Date pro banco de dados. Agora entendi valeu mesmo.